# method post in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

anyone know how to create the method submit post and the query of the coding below? since it looping can someone give me an example of the query for this?i already create the query but i don't know how to create the submit to find the answer and after submit button it can show which one is wrong answer and total score user answer it correctly

```
<?php
include "checklogin.php";

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=0 AND q_id <=3 order by rand() limit 1");
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=4 AND q_id <=6 order by rand() limit 1");
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=7 AND q_id <=9 order by rand() limit 1");
$query4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=10 AND q_id <=12 order by rand() limit 1");
$query5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=13 AND q_id <=15 order by rand() limit 1");
$query6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=16 AND q_id <=18 order by rand() limit 1");
$query7 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=19 AND q_id <=21 order by rand() limit 1");
$query8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=22 AND q_id <=24 order by rand() limit 1");
$query9 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=25 AND q_id <=27 order by rand() limit 1");
$query10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=28 AND q_id <=30 order by rand() limit 1");


    ?>


    <form action ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method ='POST'>

    <table border ='0' align ='left'>
    <tr><th>Examination Question</th></tr>

    <?php 
    //question 1
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
    ?>
<?php


    //question 2
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 3
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){ 

    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}

?>
<?php
//question 4
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query4)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 5
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query5)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 6
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query6)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 5
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query7)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 5
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query8)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 5
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query9)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
<?php
//question 5
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query10)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You also really, really, really need to read up on basic structures like loops. This code is copy-pasted to an extreme.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you should change the variables for an array:

```
<?php
include "checklogin.php";

$query = []

$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=0 AND q_id <=3 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=4 AND q_id <=6 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=7 AND q_id <=9 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=10 AND q_id <=12 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=13 AND q_id <=15 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=16 AND q_id <=18 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=19 AND q_id <=21 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=22 AND q_id <=24 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=25 AND q_id <=27 order by rand() limit 1");
$query[] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mcq_questions` WHERE q_id >=28 AND q_id <=30 order by rand() limit 1");
```

Then loop through it:

```
foreach($query as $q){
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){ 
    echo "<tr><td>$row[q_detail]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><select name ='Question_1'>
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='A'>$row[option_a]</option>
    <option value='B'>$row[option_b]</option>
    <option value='C'>$row[option_c]</option>
    td></tr>";}
}
```

This is just one way to do it.

Comment: how about the process submit?

Comment: you can access the data by the variable $_POST, I dont really understand what is the problem

Comment: the problem is i dont really how to process the submit process of the quiz, example after submitting the result it shows the the total of correct answer and it also shows which question they answer it wrongly